# Mongodb + nodejs doesn't connect with localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, web

I'm keep trying myself to connect local mongo server via nodejs.
Here's simple tutorial given by official mongodb, but doesn't hook `once` part.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("connected");
});
```

here's package.json of my project:

```
{
    "name": "MVC-Express-Application",
    "description": "An Express.js application using the MVC design pattern...",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "1.4.3",
        "errorhandler": "1.1.1",
        "express": "4.4.4",
        "express-handlebars": "1.1.0",
        "mongoose": "^3.8.8",
        "morgan": "1.1.1"
    }
}
```

when i type `mongo` they say

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
Server has startup warnings:
2017-11-07T07:58:20.003+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-11-07T07:58:20.003+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-11-07T07:58:20.003+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-11-07T07:58:20.003+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

so it should say `connected` on console but doesn't.
Anybody knows how to deal with it? I tried reinstalling mongo via `brew`.

Thanks.

macOS Sierra 10.12.6
node v7.6.0

Comment: You are missing the port 27017

Comment: adding 27017 after "localhost" didn't make things better...

Comment: what does it say when you start your app?

Comment: Presumably your starting mongo *before* you start your app? Also, what error do you get?

Comment: So here I missed the description but even I launched `mongod` and should have started the server, booting node app didn't kick the `once` part.

Comment: Strange thing here is, `error` also doesn't kick here, implies there's no connection error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the newest mongoose solved the problem right away!
Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to start the mongodb process, and for that run `mongod` in the
`Server/3.4/bin/` directory. Try connecting after that.

Comment: So here I missed the description but even I launched `mongod` and should have started the server, booting node app didn't kick the `once` part.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. Here's resoving.
in main "app.js" file use this structure:

```
`mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: 
true,useCreateIndex: true})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB has been connected!'))
.catch(error => console.log(error));`
```

Then create connection file, into that file insert this code:
    `module.exports = {
    mongoURI: "mongodb+srv://name:password@vlad-m9cz9.mongodb.net/test? 
    retryWrites=true&w=majority"     <- here is an example of link, take it from your 
    cluster connection parameter.
    };`

Then go to your file "app.js" and create variable and require connection object:
    `const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const keys = require('./config/keys');`

And in the mongoDB insert IP adress to have access to DB

that's all!